# Getting virus on my Laravel package suggest by domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

My hosting provider is saying -we have found malicious files in your account which may be infected with malware

here is the file location

```
/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php
```

[image: Port 80 blocked due to infected file]

my Laravel uses this package

https://packagist.org/packages/psy/psysh

What can be the problem? please suggest

Answer (score 4):

It's just poor threat detection from your hosting provider. Generally hackers install backdoors in hacked servers and these backdoors are called `Shells` and the file name `Shell.php` is commonly used. The hosting provider's scan is just checking the file name and triggering a false positive.

The package is safe and there is nothing to worry and you can confirm the file contents by checking it on github https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/blob/master/src/Psy/Shell.php

You should message your hosting provider to inform them that it's a false positive and carry on. I'd be more concerned as to why your hosting provider is scanning all your files.

Some references to shells

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_Shell

https://github.com/JohnTroony/php-webshells

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread on Laracasts](https://laravel.io/forum/04-09-2017-godaddy-flags-psysh-as-malware-anyone-else-seen-this), try to install you dependencies with `--no-dev`.

(`composer install --no-dev`)